# Net::SSLeay::Handle compiling error in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: perl, ssl

I've a problem to install the aforementioned module via cpanm in my multi-threading version of Perl (not the original one). 
I've Ubuntu 16.04.
When trying to compile and test this module it gives me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: impossible to find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:494: instructions set for target "blib/arch/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so" fail
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so] Error 1
-> FAIL Installing Net::SSLeay::Handle failed. See /home/my_name/.cpanm/work/1548275319.13675/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

openssl,ssllib-dev-perl,libnet-ssleay-perl, libcrypt-ssleay-perl already installed via apt-get.
I've also tried to compile manually this module, without success. I forced the installation too...no way.
The error seems linked with something missing in /usr/bin/ld: (impossible to find -lz collect2).

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Cpanm has always worked pretty well. Up to now i've been able to get all my modules installed and well functioning, apart from Net::SSLeay::Handle.

Thanks in advace for your help

Comment: Make sure you have zlib-dev or however that package is named on ubuntu?

Comment: try installing  zlib1g-dev?

Comment: That's right mate!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, i solved by installing this packages (Ubuntu 16.04LTS):

-openssl
-libssl-dev
-libnet-ssleay-perl
-libcrypt-ssleay-perl
-zlib1g-dev as suggested above

Once you're done doing that, remember to avoid testing the module when gcc will be finishing compiling it, because in most cases it fails.
So the best incantation in doing this should be as follows:

-cpanm  install -v --notest Net::SSLeay::Handle

Many thanks again to all Perl mates writing in this forum. 
You saved the day

Comment: gr8. This solution works. You just need to install those dependencies mentioned above.

Answer (score -3):

first log in cpan

```
sudo cpan
```

force intalling the module should work

```
force install Net::SSLeay::Handle
```

This should also install missing modules or notice it

Comment: This will not solve the problem which is a build issue, at best it will result in a broken installation.

Comment: You don't need to "log in". It's just a command-line program, and you can do it all at once: `cpan -f Net::SSLeay::Handle`. But, that doesn't magically make it compile correctly.